# How to disable PIN on a SIM card?

Tags: modem, mobile

On Linux, given an USB surfstick with a SIM card that has a PIN, how can I disable the PIN of the SIM card?

Note that the PIN is known, I do not want to crack it etc, just disable it.

Comment: That might depend both on the SIM model and on the modem model.

Comment: If the SIM is removable, why not putting it into a phone and clearing the PIN there?

Answer (score 6):

The following commands will allow you to remove SIM CODE from SIM card

`screen /dev/USB0` Let's assume you have a modem on /dev/ttyUSB0 (check dmesg when you plug your usb to ensure that)

The following commands will not be echoed - the easiest way is to prepare commands and copy paste to avoid typos.
Others tools than screen exists but I found screen widely used in command platform.

`ATZ` should return OK

`AT+CPIN?`
should return **+CPIN: SIM PIN** indicating SIM PIN is needed

`AT+CPIN="xxxx"` replace xxxx by your PINCODE. should return OK. you have access to the SIM

`AT+CLCK="SC",0,"xxxx"` replace xxxx by your PINCODE. disable pin code

The following keyboard sequence will exit screen: `ctrl+a k y`

Answer (score 0):

Setting the pin to `0000` usually disable it.